# Numpy: Remove last (n) elements from (m)th dimension

Tags: python, numpy

So my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('Tbars.npy')
print(np.shape(data))
```

The result i get is `(50,500,130)`

I want to get rid of the last 10 elements in the y dimension (500); so that i get `(50,490,130)`.

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried so far; where are you stuck?

Comment: Additionally, please show a sample of the data set.  What data type is `data` and what values  are contained in the structure?  I presume it’s an `ndarray`?

Comment: Are you familiar with *slicing* arrays? Can you think of a rule that tells you what slice of the array you want?

Answer (score 0):

## Initial answer, for fixed dimension to drop from and the number of elements to drop

Run:

```
data[:, :-10, :]
```

`:-10` is the way to select all elements in the respective dimension,
except the last 10.

An example for data of smaller size:

Create the array of size *(2, 10, 3)*:

```
dims = (2, 10, 3)
data = np.arange(dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2]).reshape(dims)
```

so it contains:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56],
        [57, 58, 59]]])
```

Then retrieve *data* elements except last **2** in the second dimension:

```
b = data[:, :-2, :]
```

The result is:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53]]])
```

and `b.shape` is `(2, 8, 3)`.

## A more general solution

If you want to drop last *nDrop* elements in *nDim* dimension
of *arr* array, define a function:

```
def myDrop(arr, nDim, nDrop):
    idx = [slice(None)] * arr.ndim
    idx[nDim] = slice(None, -nDrop)
    return arr[tuple(idx)]
```

Then, to retrieve a slice of *data* without last *10* elements in
dimension *1* , run:

```
b = myDrop(data, 1, 10)
```

with the same result as above.

If you want yet shorter function (actually a one-liner) define it as:

```
def myDrop2(arr, nDim, nDrop):
    return arr[tuple([slice(None, -nDrop) if i == nDim else slice(None) for i in range(arr.ndim)])]
```